# meaning of family "quasi" and the link function "inverse" in glm

Tags: r, statistics

The `glm` function in R takes a `family` argument, which can also be set to `"quasi"`. And `quasi` can have the link function set to `"inverse"`. I didn't find anything describng what those two strings stand for.

Comment: Look at `?family` instead!

Comment: `?glm` in fact tells you to do that:-"(See ‘family’ for details of family functions.)"

Comment: `family` can be set to `"inverse.gaussian"`, but I don't think it can be set to `"inverse"` ...

Comment: @nico: I checked the help for family but it just says what the arguments to quasi can be, so I know what link functions I can use but I don't know the distribution.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes, you are rigtht, inverse is a link function, so I edited my question. Still, I don't know what link function "inverse" stands for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inverse link function is just f(x) = 1/x. If you create a `family` object with the command

```
fam <- quasi(link = "inverse")
```

the link function is set to the inverse function:

```
fam$linkfun
# function (mu) 
# 1/mu
# <environment: namespace:stats>
```

By default, the link function for `quasi` is `"identity"`, i.e., f(x) = x.

The details of `quasi` can be found in the function. Have a look at the structure with

```
str(quasi())
# List of 12
#  $ family    : chr "quasi"
#  $ link      : chr "identity"
#  $ linkfun   :function (mu)  
#  $ linkinv   :function (eta)  
#  $ variance  :function (mu)  
#  $ dev.resids:function (y, mu, wt)  
#  $ aic       :function (y, n, mu, wt, dev)  
#  $ mu.eta    :function (eta)  
#  $ initialize:  expression({     n <- rep.int(1, nobs)     mustart <- y })
#  $ validmu   :function (mu)  
#  $ valideta  :function (eta)  
#  $ varfun    : chr "constant"
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "family"
```

You can access the elements with `$`, for example

```
quasi()$variance
# function (mu) 
# rep.int(1, length(mu))
# <bytecode: 0x100f30060>
# <environment: 0x101be4940>
```

to find details of `quasi`. By default, `quasi` assumes constant variance.

Comment: And what does quasi stand for?

Comment: My problem is that most of the families have names that belong to distributions, like Gaussian or Binomial, but I simply don't know any distribution named `quasi` or `quasibinomial`. So I guess for glm there is no full-blown distribution needed, just the data found in the family you showed above. Maybe there even doesn't exist any distribution with those properties, but glm doesn't care. Is that correct?

Comment: @frank In contrast to, e.g., `binomial`, `quasi` does not have all properties of a probability distribution. But you can use and modify the values to create a family with special properties.

Comment: @frank: yes. you can google "quasi-likelihood", or find a reasonable book on GLMs (McCullagh and Nelder, Venables and Ripley, Faraway ...)